# Is there a way to create dynamically <rich:tab> elements?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Let say that I want to create a variable set of `<rich:tab>` elements within a `<rich:tabPanel>` component. So I tried to do that way:

```
<rich:tabPanel switchType="client" ...>
    <ui:repeat value="#{myBean.myTabs}" var="tab">
        <rich:tab name="#{tab.name}" label="#{tab.label}"/>
    </ui:repeat>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

But it didn't work, as no tab is rendered. I also got the following message in the logs:

```
j_id174: tab panel has no enabled or rendered tabs!
```

This problem seems to be encountered by others people, for example [here](http://community.jboss.org/thread/5984).

So as suggested by the previous thread, I replaced my `<ui:repeat>` by a `<c:forEach>` but the problem still occurs.

---

I have a way to solve this problem using the `binding` attribute of my `<rich:tabPanel>` component:

```
<rich:tabPanel switchType="client" binding="#{tabNavigationBean.tabPanel}"
</rich:tabPanel>
```

and then in my Java bean:

```
private HtmlTabPanel tabPanel; // + getter and setter

public void setTabPanel(HtmlTabPanel tabPanel) {
    this.tabPanel = tabPanel;
    if (tabPanel != null) {
        createTabs();
    }
}

private void createTabs() {
    Application application = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();
    HtmlTab newTab = null;
    for (DedicatedPageTab dpt : getDedicatedPageTabs()) {
        newTab = (HtmlTab) application.createComponent(HtmlTab.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        newTab.setLabel(dpt.getLabel());
        newTab.setName(dpt.getName());
        tabPanel.getChildren().add(newTab);
    }
}
```

**This code is working**.

However, my question is to know if I can solve my problem **without** using the `binding` attribute (i.e. a 100% pure XHTML solution)?

Comment: Technical information: Java 1.6, JSF 1.2 + Facelets, Richfaces 3.3

Comment: I don't know if this would work any better, but try <a4j:repeat>?

Comment: @Naganalf also tried, with no success :(

Comment: we use '<c:forEach />' extensively to create dynamic columns for a '<rich:extendedDataTable />'. I would expect the same trick would be usable for tabPanel. Do you get any error messages when using '<c:forEach/>' ?

Comment: You should put your java solution in an answer. It's a good one.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="out">
    <rich:tabPanel>
        <c:forEach items="list" var="var">
            <rich:tab label="#{var.name}" switchType="client">
                content
            </rich:tab>
        </c:forEach>
    </rich:tabPanel>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but difficult. Here are some notes I have:

Use c:forEach to create tab tags inside tabPanel inside outputPanel. reRender outputPanel on tab removal, add, or name change

http://relation.to/11633.lace

http://devharbor.blogspot.com/2009/08/add-jsf-controls-dynamically-with.html

---

We also made use of templating, though I still have an outstanding issue for it: [How to force the build phase in a JSF 1.2 page using JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6298189/147265)

http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#template
    Docs on templating

http://www.jsfcentral.com/articles/facelets_3.html
    Templating tutorial