# How dynamically generate ace:tabPane components?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

I am using JSF 2.1 and ICEFaces 2 and I have a tabset like:

```
<ace:tabSet clientSide="true">
    <ace:tabPane>
        <f:facet name="label">My First Tab</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="One"></h:outputText>
    </ace:tabPane>
    <ace:tabPane>
        <f:facet name="label">Second Tab</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="Two"></h:outputText>
    </ace:tabPane>
    <ace:tabPane>
        <f:facet name="label">Third Tab</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="Third"></h:outputText>
    </ace:tabPane>
</ace:tabSet>
```

Instead of hardcoding the tabPanes, I want to generate them dynamically based on a list. How can I achieve this by standard JSF or ICEFaces components?

I tried to use the `<ui:repeat>`, but it doesn't work:

```
<ui:repeat var="o" value="#{bean.myList}" varStatus="status">
    <ace:tabPane>
        <f:facet name="label">#{o.name}</f:facet>
        <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{o.valuesArray}" layout="pageDirection">
            <f:selectItems value="#{o.checkboxes}" />
        </h:selectManyCheckbox>
    </ace:tabPane>
</ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't do ICEFaces, but you're encountering basically [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022193/is-there-a-way-to-create-dynamically-richtab-elements) as RichFaces has with its `<rich:tab>`. As there exist no hypothetical `<rich:tabs>` (like as `<rich:columns>` which would be the dynamic variant of `<rich:column>`/`<h:column>`), one would have to use the view build time JSTL `<c:forEach>` tag to prepare the JSF view with those tags. You could apply the same on your ICEFaces page:

```
<ace:tabSet clientSide="true">
  <c:forEach items="#{bean.tabs}" var="tab">
    <ace:tabPane>
      <f:facet name="label">#{tab.label}</f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{tab.name}"></h:outputText>
    </ace:tabPane>
  </c:forEach>
</ace:tabSet>
```

Note that this will only fail if `#{bean}` is not a real managed bean, but an expression which in turn depends on an evaluation of another JSF component, such as `<h:dataTable var="bean">`.

The `<ui:repeat>` won't work as it's a render-time tag. It won't dynamically generate multiple JSF components before the JSF component tree is been built.

#### See also:

- [ICEFaces issue 6527 - Dynamically adding/removing `ace:tabPane` Results in `ace:tabset` Retrieving Entire Tabset Content](http://jira.icefaces.org/browse/ICE-6527)
- [ICEFaces issue 6560 - New `ace:tabs` dynamic tabset component](http://jira.icefaces.org/browse/ICE-6560;jsessionid=927D82111E1B79775EF7785D2A682A85?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.ext.subversion:subversion-commits-tabpanel)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can write like this:

```
<ice:panelTabSet var="tab" value="#{mainTabsTempl.tabs}">
    <ice:panelTab label="#{tab.label}">
         body
    </ice:panelTab>
</ice:panelTabSet>
```

It's not `tabSet` tag, but have the same work.

Comment: it doesn't support client side navigation, it's only server side