# How to use <h:form> in <rich:tabPanel>

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, tabpanel

I'm developing my first JSF2 + Richfaces application and now I have this problem.

I have the following rich:tabPanel to which add and remove dynamically tab.

```
<h:form>
  <rich:tabPanel id="tabsPanel" switchType="ajax" activeItem="#{tabsBean.activeTab}" >
     <c:forEach var="tab" items="#{tabsBean.tabs}" styleClass="myRightPanel">
        <rich:tab  name="#{tab.name}" styleClass="myTab" >
            <h:form id="#{tab.name}" >
            <ui:include src="#{tab.pathDaIncludere}" />
        </h:form>
    </rich:tab>
   </c:forEach> 
  </rich:tabPanel>
</h:form>
```

but to run I must add a `<h:form>` around each `<rich:tab>` otherwise the actions in the tabs will not work.

Is correct insert `<h:form>` in each tab?

Comment: @Daniel that might end up being worse; I'd rather use a4j:region instead

Comment: Nested forms have their own issues. I suggest you remove that `h:form` from inside the tabs and change the `c:forEach` for an `a4j:repeat`.

Comment: As @Gamb says you've nothing to do with nested forms. Use only one which surrounds the whole `tabPanel` or one for each `tab`. In the other hand I think you are bound to use `c:forEach`, as tabPanel has to know about his tags before page rendering. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022193/is-there-a-way-to-create-dynamically-richtab-elements

Comment: @XtremeBiker You have a point about the `c:forEach`. I take back that part of my previous comment. The OP just has to make sure that the `tabsBean.tabs` collection is properly populated with the right tabs when re-rendering (if that's the intention).

Comment: There's no way to dynamically build it using `ui:repeat`. That's an advantage in libraries like Primefaces, where `tabView` component has a built-in iterator and you can build a model before rendering it. `<p:tabView value="#{bean.list}" var="listItem">`. That just avoid introducing more logic into the view.